# Prefix all endpoints with "/api" or another prefix, in spring reactive web (webflux)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I have a set of RestControllers in a spring reactive web project and I want to prefix all of the controllers with "api" or "test-api" in different environments.

I have tried to use `server.servlet.context-path=/api` and it's not working with spring reactive web (webflux) running on Netty server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a placeholders in @RequestMapping, like for example @RequestMapping("${foo.bar}") ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The following property was added in spring boot 2.3 to achieve this with webflux

```
spring.webflux.base-path
```

Release Notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#configurable-base-path-for-webflux-applications